# How do you match anything after some character unless there is a trailing slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to return true if the variable contains "/agency/:something", I achived this by using: [/agency/.*](https://regex101.com/r/xNOtzF/1). The problem is, I dont want to match "/agency/:somethig/:morestuff", and the regex I wrote do match.

```
const whitelist = [
    '\/agency\/.*',
    '\/agenzia\/.*'
];

const re = new RegExp(whitelist.join("|"));

console.log(re.test("/agency"));     //FALSE
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo")); //TRUE
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo/bar")); //TRUE (But I need it to be false)
```

How can I extend the Regex to make it return false in the last console.log statement?

Comment: What about `/agency/foo/`?

Comment: `^[^/]*/agency/[^/]*$` works, or you may not.

Comment: Or better: `/^\/agen(?:cy|zia)?/[^\/]+\/?$/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `^` and `$` to tell your RegEx to start at the start of your String and end at the end.

Plus, use `[^\/]` instead of `.` to avoid the extra `/`

```js
const whitelist = [
    '^\/agency\/[^\/]*$',
    '^\/agenzia\/[^\/]*$'
];

const re = new RegExp(whitelist.join("|"));

console.log(re.test("/agency"));     //FALSE
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo")); //TRUE
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo/bar")); //FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside a non capturing group for the `whitelist.join("|")` and after that match using a negated character class `[^\/]+` until you encounter a forward slash.

Use `^` to assert the begin of the line and  `$` to assert the end of the line.

```js
const whitelist = [
  '\/agency\/',
  '\/agenzia\/'
];

const re = new RegExp("^(?:" + whitelist.join("|") + ")[^\/]+$");
console.log(re.test("/agency"));
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo"));
console.log(re.test("/agency/foo/bar"));
```